# Твердое покрытие — дорог или оборудованных мест?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, синтаксис

Ст.65 Водного кодекса РФ, пункт 15, п.п. 4: ...запрещается движение и стоянка транспортных средств (кроме специальных транспортных средств), за исключением их движения по дорогам и стоянки на дорогах и в специально оборудованных местах, имеющих твердое покрытие.

*К чему относится понятие **твердое покрытие**:* только к специально оборудованным местам или ко всему — дорогам и оборудованным местам?

Comment: Если добавить "в водоохранной зоне"(что Вы опустили) -  всё становится на свои места. Нельзя, чтобы транспортные средства устраивали "свинорой" в водоохранной зоне ибо он приводит к кошмарным последствиям при осадках, таяния снега, оползнях. И тогда отпадает возможность ссылаться на то, что "данный текст допускает неоднозначное толкование". Штраф(солидный) или штрафы придется платить всё равно, несмотря на обращение к участникам сообщества "Русский язык"

Comment: На сколько я понимаю, вы не можете сопоставить  данный вопрос с пунктуацией в русском языке, уходя в дебри "водоохранной зоны" ... если бы вы были чуточку внимательны, то заметили бы, сначала чётко указано 

Ст.65 Водного кодекса РФ, пункт 15, п.п. 4: .... но думаю это не столь важно для поставленного вопроса о пунктуации.

Comment: Непонятно, при чем тут пунктуация. Хотя вопрос о четкой формулировке нормы Закона здесь, несомненно, есть. Не было бы неоднозначного толкования, если бы законодатель написал  иначе. "15. В границах водоохранных зон запрещается:
4) движение и стоянка транспортных средств (кроме специальных транспортных средств), за исключением их движения по дорогам с твердым покрытием и стоянки на таких дорогах и в специально оборудованных местах, имеющих твердое покрытие.

Comment: А пока этого нет, судья все равно будет безжалостно выносить штрафы на физических лиц до 4,5 тысяч рублей, а вот на юридических лиц - до 400 000 рублей(!). Несмотря на то, что "текст допускает неоднозначное толкование". И все жалобы суды отклоняют, суммы штрафов остаются без изменения.

Comment: Что вас так тянет на юридическую сторону вопроса... вас что ранее наказали по этой статье ? ) Если вас так интересует, могу предоставить информацию от прокуратуры по этому вопросу. Они однозначно в один голос утверждают .............. )))))))))) и не какого наказания в виде штрафа не последует !   :-)

Comment: Потому, что пунктуация не изменит тут ничего. Вы задали вопрос, на который нет ответа. Формулировка нормы права не точна. Уверен, что Вы это понимали заранее.

Comment: Законы РФ имеет твёрдую трактовку основанную на использовании русского языка  и опирающиеся на правильное использование орфографии и пунктуации. Иного не дано )))) Решение с правильным ответом есть.

Comment: Геннадий@  Я бы рекомендовал Вам обратиться с Вашим вопросом к автору незатейливой формулировки, которую мы тут обсуждаем. Из-за неточно изложенной нормы права может возникать правовая коллизия(и, наверняка, уже возникала не однажды). У законодателя свои эксперты в сфере русского языка, наша самодеятельная компания им не указ. Можно обратиться в суд, это тоже может быть эффективно. Только все это медленно происходит. Мы можем твердить про себя как мантру: "Законы РФ имеет твёрдую трактовку",  "иного не дано", но  исправить даже очевидную невнятность в Законе может только его автор.

Comment: Спасибо Варяг-91. Думаю пора закрыть эту тему для Вас. Если интересует правильный ответ _ ТВЁРДОЕ ПОКРЫТИЕ , ТОЛЬКО К СТОЯНКЕ )))) Юридический аспект для меня как не превалировал в начале , так и остаётся третистепенным... КАЗНИТЬ НЕЛЬЗЯ ПОМИЛОВАТЬ !!!!

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, данный текст допускает неоднозначное толкование. Несмотря на разные предлоги, одинаковый падеж при желании позволяет соотнести "покрытие" с обоими упоминаниями "на дорогах" и "в местах".

Как разобраться по смыслу в спорном юридическом случае? С одной стороны, можно предположить, что к дороге (для того, чтобы она считалась дорогой, а не самовольно накатанной колеёй) предъявляется требование постоянства (твёрдости покрытия). Тогда, если на ней можно стоять, то можно и ездить по ней. С другой стороны, из предложения грамматически не следует требование твердости покрытия дороги, по которой "допускается движение", но тогда возникает логическое противоречие: стоять можно только на твёрдой дороге, а ездить можно по любой. Это приводит к выводу, что законодатель относит требование твёрдого покрытия только к "оборудованным местам" вне дорог, не затрагивая определения "что является дорогой". Можно было сделать текст более однозначным по смыслу, например:  "... в имеющих твердое покрытие специально оборудованных местах".

Comment: «Дорога» — обустроенная или приспособленная и используемая для движения транспортных средств полоса земли либо поверхность искусственного сооружения.
Источник: http://voditeliauto.ru/voditeli-i-gibdd/pdd/ponyatiya/doroga.html

Comment: "...(для того, чтобы она считалась дорогой, а не самовольно накатанной колеёй) предъявляется требование постоянства (твёрдости покрытия)..." Зачем придумывать самодельные определения, если определение "дорога" имеется в правовой практике.Это не вопрос Русского языка, это вопрос абсолютно юридический и экологический. Спрашивающий не упомянул, что запрет движения и стоянки относится к "водоохранной зоне". За нарушение положен солидный штраф.Конечно же, в правовой практике "твердое покрытие" должны иметь и дороги и стоянки.

Comment: Вопрос  не правовой. Интересен разбор предложенного текста с точки пунктуации и вложенного смысла. Если вас интересует правовая сторона, то действительно в каждом регионе её интерпретируют на своё усмотрение ))))) Вопрос конкретный:  к  чему относиться словосочетание "ТВЁРДОЕ ПОКРЫТИЕ" с точки зрения пунктуации  русского языка,  так как в РФ законы пишутся именно на русском языке :-)

Comment: Одной только пунктуацией здесь нельзя изменить смысл в пользу одной из двух версий: если вы поставите запятую после "на дорогах", то стоянка в спец. обор. местах окажется запрещённой. В исходном варианте смысл неоднозначен, хотя и ближе к тому, что "покрытия" относятся только к "местам" (так поймёт большинство прочитавших) - за счёт того, что причастный оборот примыкает ко второму понятию. Но вторую трактовку формально нельзя исключить.

Comment: Дополнительные запятые ставить и убирать не надо, они уже проставлены для придания юридической и смысловой нагрузки данному закону. Вопрос стоял только один (и простой) - к чему относиться словосочетание "ТВЁРДОЕ ПОКРЫТИЕ"

Comment: В формулировке " к чему относиться словосочетание " мягкий знак в слове "относитЬся" совершенно излишен, увы. Где-где, а на сайте "Русский язык" следует быть более грамотным. А Вы написали это даже дважды.

Answer (score 1):

Твердое покрытие — дорог или оборудованных мест?

Только **"специально оборудованных мест"**.

Как тут справедливо заметили, законы в России пишутся на русском языке и читаться должны тоже по-русски.

Из учебника русского языка:
"Относясь к именам существительным, **причастия (причастные обороты)**, являющиеся в предложении **определениями**, согласуются с существительным **в роде, числе и падеже**".

В нашем случае причастный оборот **"имеющих твердое покрытие"** (предложный падеж) является ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЕМ и никак не согласуется в падеже с **"их движения по дорогам"** (дательный падеж). 
 Никто не говорит и не пишет так:
"за исключением их движения по дорог**АМ**, имеющ**ИХ** твердое покрытие".
Если бы "твердое покрытие" относилось и к "дорогам", то правильно говорить и писать так:
"за исключением их движения по дорог**АМ**, имеющ**ИМ** твердое покрытие".

Теперь о "стоянке на дорогах".
Казалось бы, причастный оборот **"имеющИХ твердое покрытие"** может относиться и к **"за исключением их стоянки на дорогах"**, так как согласуется **в роде, числе и падеже**, и правилами допускается отношение одного определения к нескольким существительным. Но есть одно "НО" — эти существительные должны быть перечислены через запятую или соединительный союз "и" и не иметь **повторяющихся предлогов**. Если есть такие предлоги, то определение (причастный оборот) относится только к ближайшему существительному.
 Поэтому в нашем случае в предложении "за исключением их движения по дорогАМ и стоянки на дорогАХ и в специально оборудованных местАХ, имеющИХ твердое покрытие", причастный оборот "имеющИХ твердое покрытие", являющийся определением, относится только к существительному "местах".

Не было бы предлога "в" перед "специально оборудованных местАХ", тогда "имеющих твердое покрытие" относилось бы и к "стоянки на дорогах".

Есть и правовой аспект.
Если в водоохранной зоне по дороге без твердого покрытия разрешено движение, что доказано однозначно, то запретить стоянку на ней могут только **Правила Дорожного Движения**. Не Водный, не Земельный, не Воздушный кодексы и иные законы и подзаконные акты, а только  **ПДД**! К счастью в них нет пока пункта, запрещающего стоянку на дорогах, пролегающих в водоохранных зонах.

И еще, есть такое понятие как **"дороги общего пользования"**, занесенные в Перечни дорог общего пользования. Они бывают как с твердым покрытием, так и грунтовые. И никто не в праве запретить движение по ним, где бы они ни пролегали, пока они имеют этот статус. Могут вводиться только временные ограничение и прекращение движения по ним при ремонте, непогоде и т. д.

**"Закон о дорогах и дорожной деятельности", ст-ст 28, 30.**
Как ни крути, этот закон и Водный кодекс не могли быть приняты с противоречиями.

Что касается трактовки природоохранными и надзорными органами абсолютного большинства регионов РФ п. 4, ч. 15, ст. 65 Водного кодекса в свою пользу, т. е. в пользу запрета на движение и стоянку на грунтовых дорогах в водоохранных зонах, то что тут скажешь...
**поколение ЕГЭ**! 
Невольно вспоминаются слова таксиста из к/ф "Брат - 2": "Были же люди как люди, и вдруг все стали де...ми!"
Как-то так.

Answer (score 0):

Всё очень просто - к чему относится словосочетание ТВЁРДОЕ ПОКРЫТИЕ. В ст. 65 Водного кодекса РФ пункт 15, пп. 4 ответ однозначный - только к транспортным средствам, причём ко всем, а не только  к специальным транспортным средствам.

Сколько у нас переправ и мостов через реки, и все они находятся в водоохранной зоне. Если бы словосочетание относилось только к спецтехнике, то, проезжая через мост,  мы бы нарушали этот закон (а некоторые из нас по нескольку раз в день) и нас смело можно штрафовать!