# Причастный оборот к чему отнести?

Tags: грамотная-речь, причастный-оборот

В предложении "Запрещено движение и стоянка транспортных средств , за исключением их движения по дорогам и стоянки на дорогах и в специально оборудованных местах, имеющих твердое покрытие."причастный оборот "имеющих твердое покрытие" относится ко всему предложению или только к "специально оборудованным местам"?

Comment: Этот вопрос уже задавался несколько раз, например: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/432945/%d0%a2%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82

Answer (score 0):

Конечно же, оборот относится только к сочетанию "специально оборудованных местах". Было бы странно отнести его к конструкции "транспортных средств". Тем более, как я считаю, если это официальный документ, здесь не может быть сочетаний, запутывающих читателя, во избежание непредвиденных ситуаций. Поэтому считать, что главное слово и причастный оборот разорваны некоторыми членами, неуместно.